# Mipmap generation fails second time

Tags: opengl

I have the following situation: I have a material with a texture which I load from file.In some cases I just load the image, create OpenGL texture and generate mipmaps.Then just render it.Works fine when minimized.In other cases,I do some processing on that texture after the initial mipmaps generation.And because I do the processing only on the level zero I regenerate the mipmaps before returning to the renderer.The issue is that after second generation of mipmaps they don't exist.The texture looks as if it has GL_NEAREST mag and min.I can't understand why it doesn't work second time.Here is my code to generate mipmaps:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,_id);   
glTexParameteri  ( _target, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0 );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);  
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);                       
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
```

My hardware is NVidia QUADRO K4000 ,OpenGL 4.2

One more thing.In OpenGL debug output I am getting the following warning:

> State usage warning: Texture 2 is base level inconsistent.Check texture size.Severity:low
>   ,ID131204

I also debugged with gDebugger and it clearly shows number of mipmaps = 1 after second generation while after first generation it is 10.Btw,second time it is already different texture object which got it's data from the initial texture.

Comment: What is `_target` value? What is textures width and height?

Comment: GL_TEXTURE_2D   ,width and height are arbitrary...The aren't power of 2

Comment: Have you called `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`? That one's bitten me before.

Comment: Looks quite ok. Are you sure texture data is initialised at this moment (TexImage2D was called with non-NULL texels array)? E.g. you haven't destroyed texture in between.

Comment: @keltar sure,the texture id is valid when I bind it for generation.

Comment: Did you tried without second line? and specify GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL?

Comment: glTexParameteri  ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 10 );  did the job !!! can you explain why?I didn't need it for the first time at all!

Comment: GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL - should be specified depends to your texture size. With this parameter you saying how many mipmaps you want down.
Looks like without this specification your GPU can't get what needs to do, or something wrong. actually, I have no idea why it works first time. Happy that it helps you :)

Comment: In the specs (Red book V8) said that if GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL isn't specified then all the levels down to 1x1 pixel will be generated...