# OpenGL objects cleanup after context destruction

Tags: opengl

I have been experiencing some strange bugs in my OpenGL 4.x program.They are strange because they are both inconsistent and happen under conditions which seem to be completely unrelated.In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763040/cant-generate-mipmaps-with-off-screen-opengl-context-on-linux) I describe some of the anomalies.

Now, after further investigations I paid attention that if I am using more than one instance of some specific type of shader program I am getting those bugs more frequently.Also I found that not all my OpenGL handles (like shader programs, FBOs, textures) are deleted before the context destruction (That's another bug I should take care of).

So I am having a pretty weird theory  that some of the explicitly  undeleted GL objects from the last execution still "stay alive" in GPU memory and interfere with the current program objects?How much is it likely to happen?AFAIK when the context is destroyed all the related objects should be swept from that context related memory block.

Comment: Are you using context sharing? That will significantly complicate the lifetime of certain OpenGL objects (the shareable variety).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman No I don't.It is always one context in a main thread per process.

Comment: I was about to ask you the same question, we had a similar problem a while ago. Are you sure you are not using a third party that creates a new temporary context, shares the objects then delete the temporary context?

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu Nope.I use GLFW to init the context.Then it is killed at the app exit.I found though a bug related to the order of destruction of the objects in the framework which causes some of them to be destroyed after the context has been killed.That's why I am asking if it is possible that non explicitly destructed GL programs are still alive and cause glitches with the new ones.

Comment: Btw,deletion of GL objects after context is dead cause GL error of GL_INVALID_OPERATION   which seems to be logical in such a case.

Comment: That said, there is also the possibility that the card reuse resources for some optimization. Do you have the same problems with other hardware/drivers?

Comment: @Jean-SimonBrochu it happens also on the latest driver on Linux.